# Error with the inflate method of the onCreateOptionsMenu in Android in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[image: Error as seen]

But what could be the soltion to this? I've google and gotten tired with no sensible answer! 
My menu folder looks contains the my_menu.xml file and is situated as shown below;[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `yourpackage.R` and **NOT** the `android.R` class, when trying to inflate the menu?

Comment: @rekaszeru  How do I tell that am using mypackage.R and not the android.R class?

Comment: Take a look at the import section at the top of your class. Do you have the `import android.R;` there?

Comment: Actually, its now underling the 'R' in red! Things just got worse!

Answer (score 1):

Oh guys, I got the solution yeey! The problem was with the AndroidManifest.xml file! FIrst and foremost, the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml was not well defined! Secondly, I have noticed that errors in the 'src' folder originate from the 'res' folder i.e the xml files! At one point, I had all my java classes preceded by an error mark! Great thanks to @rekaszeru for the eye opener! Kudos!